# How to remove UISplitViewController Master Navigation Blur Tint

Tags: uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, blur, tvos

I am creating a tvOS app that uses a UISplitViewController and in the Master View Controller side is a table (like what is created by default) and I cannot figure out what is bluring at the top and bottom of the table. The blurring occurs more after scrolling the table down a few items pushing the top table cell item up. It appears to be a Navigation Bar background that is blurred gray at the top, but also at the bottom of the table, and it overlays the table view. I cannot figure out what it is and there does not appear to be any documentation on what it is either. I even tried using the Storyboard views Debug View Hierarchy but cannot seem to figure out how to get rid of this gray blur effect. It would be nice to change it's tint color if Apple wants to keep it in the tvOS table view appearance.

Can anyone figure out what this is and how to change it or turn it off? It only seems to appear in the tvOS table view. See attached images.

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was provided this answer in another forum:

dabinat

Nov 1, 2015 1:02 AM

(in response to jpcoates)

I had exactly the same problem and eventually figured out that it was just a mask that was added to the top of the table. You can disable it with the following:

self.tableView.maskView = nil;